# Matlab code for continued fraction

Tags: matlab, continued-fractions

I want to use continued fraction for digital watermarking. I need to evaluate a number using the concept of continued fraction.
Can anyone provide the matlab code for continued fractions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`rat`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rat.html) function:

```
>> rat(0.23)

ans =

0 + 1/(4 + 1/(3 + 1/(-8)))
```

The output of this function is a string. If you want to parse this output, you can refer to [this topic](http://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/67367).

**Edit:**

If you want to have only positive numbers in the resulting expansion, then you can achieve this through editing rat.m (`edit rat.m`). See [this topic](http://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/68191).

Basically, you need to change line 100 of rat.m from `d = round(x)` to `d = floor(x)`. If you don't want to change the Matlab sources, you can save a copy of the new rat.m somewhere and even change the name of the function if you'd like.

With the modified rat function:

```
>> rat(0.23)

ans =

0 + 1/(4 + 1/(2 + 1/(1 + 1/(7))))
```

Comment: Sanik: Note that you can use `eval` to get the result of this expression. Didn't know about `rat`... +1 :)

Comment: But rat gives me the negative values which I don't want. How can it be avoided?

Comment: Added a possible fix to get positive values.